# UIlabel truncating text after linebreaks in iOS7 only

Tags: ios7, uilabel, line-breaks

I am trying to display a **UIlabel** with a text having a **linebreak**. It works fine on iOS6 but on iOS7 , it truncates the text after linebreak is encountered.

I have kept

> label.numberOfLines = 1;

The UIlabel frame which I am setting is also correct. I have cross checked it.

Does anyone has any other pointers to this problem?

Comment: Can you please tell me exactly what is your problem?

Comment: My problem is , in iOS6 UIlabel displays the text completely even after the linebreak is encountered , whereas in IOS7 when the uilabel text has linebreak , the text after linebreak is not displayed.

Comment: ok i got your problem

Comment: Do you know for possible solution?

Comment: actually i'm checking for your solution in my current app

Comment: @XYZ I have got the same error, please help if you got any solution.

Answer (score 0):

label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

This will allow the label to dynamically assign as many lines into the label as will fit into the label.frame.size.height of the label based on the current font.